# how to get the style width value set in the css style rule or the html tag style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get a textarea element's width, as shown in the Chrome inspect's Element tab either by a css rule or the element's inline style, if none of the css rules apply to the element or they are overridden by the inline style.  I want to set a span's max-width to the textarea's width value, and then copy a line of text from the textarea into the span and determine if and how that line wraps.

However, when I use `jQuery css( 'width' )`, `document.querySelector( 'textarea' ).style.width`, and `window.getComputedStyle( document.querySelector( 'textarea' ).getPropertyValue( 'width' )`, the return values are often not the values set by the rule or by the inline style in the element's tag.

In my case the above methods return 131.818px instead of 150p, a enough of a difference that I can't use the above methods.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

```js
var $textarea = $( 'textarea' );
var textarea  = $textarea[ 0 ];
var $p        = $( 'p' );
var p         = $p[ 0 ];

p.innerHTML = "The following are textarea <b>width</b> values,<br />" +
              "but they aren't the value set in the style tag textarea rule:<br /><br />" +
              "<t />jQuery css( 'width' ) result: '" + $textarea.css( 'width' ) + "'<br />" +
              "<t/>computed width: '"  +
              window.getComputedStyle( document.querySelector( 'textarea' ) )
              .getPropertyValue( 'width' ) + "'<br />" +
              "<t/>style.width value: " +
              "'" + textarea.style.width + "'" + "'<br />";
```

```css
textarea {
  height: auto;
  width:  150px;
}
t::before {
  content: "...."
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>Line 1

line 3

Line 5 - A long line intended to wrap because it is longer than the textarea's specified width.
Line 6 - A short line.

Line 8 - Another long line, that should also wrap.

Line 9</textarea>

<p></p>
```

I can get the width value by parsing the outerHTML property of the element's inline style assignment and/or get it from the style tags by parsing their rules when the inline-style doesn't set the width, but this is more difficult than it seems like it should be to get the unchanged width value.

Any ideas on how I could best do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to textarea styles and it should display value correctly

```
textarea {
  height: auto;
  width:  150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the simple way to get the value I needed.